# Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method error

Tags: java, android, class, android-studio

This is my code that is suppose to change some text on button press:-

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    TextView txtview;
    Button butto;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
        txtview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        butto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttn);

        butto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void Onclick(View paramView) {
                txtview.setText("You Clicked it!");
            }
        });

    }}
```

The `View.OnClickListener` is underlined and it gives me the error "Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method". This code has been mostly copied from the internet and its suppose to be working fine. Probably its a Android Studio error only. How can I get it to work?

Comment: it should be `@Override public void onClick(View v){ }`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`View.OnClickListener` must implement the function `onClick()` otherwise your class should be abstract, so that you could implement your `onClick()` function in some child class. But in your case you have made a spelling mistake. It should be `onClick()` instead of `Onclick()`;

Answer (score 9):

You got the method name wrong :

```
public void Onclick(View paramView)
```

should be

```
public void onClick(View paramView)
```

Following Java naming conventions can help you.

Answer (score -1):

Tricks: add `@Override` above `onClick(View)`. Without `@Override`, the warning means you didn't implement `onClickListener`.

Comment: How to make annonoymous inner class abstract?

Comment: Sorry, what? I'm afraid I didn't get it.