# Is it possible to declare anonymous class as abstract?

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract, anonymous-class

I am trying to find out, if it is possible to create anonymous inner class as abstract. 
I thought, that it doesn't make sense because I am trying to create instance of the abstract class, but the message from compiler confused me: 

Class 'Anonymous class derived from Test' must either be **declared abstract** or implement abstract method 'method()' in Test

Code:

```
abstract class Test{
    abstract void method();
}
Test o = new Test(){};
```

If it is possible to declare anonymous class as abstract, please let me know how to do that.

I would be greatful for answer.

Comment: In what circumstances would it make sense to do this?

Comment: You can't declare an anonymous class abstract: by definition, you are creating an instance of a new class when you declare an anonymous class, meaning it's got to be concrete.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth As I mentioned, I don't see any sense but I am trying to understand the compiler message.

Comment: abstract classes cannot be used directly only via a sub-class but you can't have a sub-class of an anonymous class as it doesn't have a name you can use, so it would be pointless.

Comment: The compiler message is just an artifact of a generalization. The compiler simply uses the same text fragment for all cases, in which an inherited abstract method is not implemented.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [JLS Sec 15.9.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.9.5) (emphasis mine):

> ## 15.9.5. Anonymous Class Declarations
>
> An anonymous class declaration is automatically derived from a class instance creation expression by the Java compiler.
>
> An anonymous class **is never abstract** (§8.1.1.1).
>
> An anonymous class is always implicitly final (§8.1.1.2).
>
> An anonymous class is always an inner class (§8.1.3); it is never static (§8.1.1, §8.5.1).

Answer (score 0):

you can't and  does not make sense to declare anonymous class as abstract class as anonymous are  used as local class only once.

i think you are getting this error because of similar issue [Class must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29789057/class-must-either-be-declared-abstract-or-implement-abstract-method-error)

Answer (score 0):

As quoted by Andy Turner the answer to your question is NO.

However I think you wanted to know something different.

**Why do you get this compiler message?**

Well the compiler is a bit misleading here. It offers two possible solutions based on that you are declaring a class (that anonymous class) and then also want to create an instance of that class:

1. make the derived class (which an anonymous class always is) abstract,
   this is fine for normal and inner classes but it is not possible for  anonymous classes, so the compiler should not suggest it in the first place
2. implement all methods and have no abstract methods in your anonymous class declaration

**So to solve your actual problem:** simply implement `method()` so your anonymous class declaration contains no more abstract methods

```
abstract class Test{
    abstract void method();
}
Test o = new Test()
{
  void method()
  {
    // do something 
  };
};
```

Now everything is declared and the compiler should not complain any more.